# Which test to use from a paired data that has only 4 cases of information from each group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I have a question from an exam:

A Statistics Professor believes that adding videos of statisticians consulting on applied problems to
her standard instructional material will help students solve problems. She designs an experiment to find
evidence to support this hypothesis. A total of 167 students are given a test prior to receiving her class
(the “pretest”) to see how they solve applied statistics problems. The pretest is graded Pass or Fail. The
students are then randomly divided into two groups: The Experimental Group with 106 students, and the
Control Group with 61 students. Over the next 2 weeks, the Experimental group are shown videos plus
her standard instructional material, while the Control group receives only her standard instructional
material. After this is done, all students take the same Pass/Fail test again on solving applied statistics
problems (the “post-test”). You can assume that all students are independent. The following are the
combined Pretest Posttest outcomes:[image]

a) Using only the data for the experimental group is there statistically significant evidence of an
improvement between Pretest and Posttest performance.? What is the Null Hypothesis; the
Alternative Hypothesis, and show the details for the test used ?

b) Using only the data for the control group is there statistically significant evidence of an improvement
between the pretest and posttest?

Comment: Use McNemar's test.